# Power BI and snowflake pass thru sql

Tags: powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, m

I'm trying to embed some sql in my power bi advanced editor using M.

It looks like this per table;
[This is the default Power BI query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBVbb.png)

I'd like to insert a select query somewhere in there; I've tried replacing the Name= with a Query=

Scott

Answer (score 0):

The Snowflake connector in Power BI does not support SQL queries, only table load.  It was planned for release March 2021, but doesn't appear to have been included.

For release notification, you can follow the [Snowflake connector -> add SQL statement as optional](https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=25342316-0a28-401e-a6ad-9d7740a5dce8) feature request at Power BI Ideas.